# which WPF control can have grid as a child

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, parent-child

I would like to know - which WPF control can have grid as a child as I want to insert grid to control (dynamically)

Comment: what did you try? Can you explain better? To my knowledge one of the  cool things of WPF is that you can really easily nest controls, like a treeview where in every item you put anything you want...

Comment: you can nest grid into grid without problem. As above, can you explain better your needs?

Comment: I have something like 15 grids and I wont to put them in on control with some kind of navigation ... something like tabs panel but instead of tabs I would like to have arrow or page number

Comment: With a lot of imagination, i read "Which ItemsControl can have a Grid as the ItemsPanel" :) And who voted this one up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any control that inherits from `ContentControl` is capable of containing **any** other single control, and any control that inherits from `Panel` can contain multiple instances of any other control.

In practice, this means that a large number of controls can potentially contain your `Grid`.  If you only want a single `Grid` to appear in the control, and you do not need any other specific behaviour, I would recommend using an instance of `ContentControl`